# Use of substring function with length parameter filled from column value

Tags: swift, swift3, sqlite.swift

I want to create `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT substr(fileNameWithSuffix, 1, length(fileNameWithSuffix) - length(suffix))
AS fileName FROM someTable
```

However SQLite.swift seems to only allow fixed length parameter in substring.

Declaration of `substring` function:

```
public func substring(_ location: Int, length: Int? = nil) -> Expression<UnderlyingType>
```

I need something like this:

```
public func substring(_ location: Int, length: Expression<Int>) -> Expression<UnderlyingType>
```

Is there any way how to create this `SELECT` without writing it myself?